# Python: read excel row and enter into database based on columns

Tags: python, xlrd

I have an excel sheet that I need to read and enter information into the database. But I need to check each column and enter rows according to the column value. I am using xlrd

[image]

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Users\\ed\\Documents\perfomance.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
rowval = sheet.row_values(1,1)
for r in rowval:
   print(r) #I am getting the rows I want here (IT, HR, Admin, Delivery)
```

I need to check the column value and insert the rows from the specific column into the database.

So if it is IT, I need to enter the values of the IT column. Can you advice me how I can do that? eventually I must get all the values into the database.

I am doing the following:

```
for i in range(1, sheet.ncols): 
            dept= sheet.cell_value(1, i)                
            for j in range(sheet.nrows):
                if dept == 'IT':                    
                   metval = sheet.cell_value(j, i)
                
        values = (metval)

        query = "INSERT INTO statvalues (dept) VALUES (%s)"
        # Execute sql Query
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        
        # Close the cursor
        cursor.close()

        # Commit the transaction
        database.commit()
```

But Is there a way to get the column name and insert without having to do it manually?

Comment: What have you tried for yourself? Is there anything you encountered or ran into? There are numerous ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @Ludo21South, I've updated my question as to what I am doing. I am manually entering dept name, but I dont want to do that. I want to read the name from the column and insert into the db

Comment: Most likely you could, but that would mean that it is more error prone. In that case you need to ensure the columns never change and the data received shouldn't either ("IT" is different from "it" in some databases).  Not quite sure what it is you want to achieve?